# Is it possible for multiple Application Masters to reside on the same node in YARN?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Application Master(AM) is per application, so lets say there are multiple applications running on a YARN cluster. In such scenario is it ever possible that multiple AMs belonging to multiple application happen to exist on the same node at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is possible that there can be multiple application master on same node. But each of these must belong to different applications and none of them will be aware about presence of other.

for more details you can also refer to http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html (YARN apache docs) or you can also refer to "Hadoop definitive guide" by tom white (edition 5 , page no -80 ,Topic - Anatomy of YARN application run).

Hope this is helpful.